# File "C:\Python38-32\lib\os.py", line 411 Syntax Error

Tags: python

I'm working to build a python 3.8 script to load a csv file that is in a Google Cloud Storage bucket to a given table in one of the datasets of the Google Cloud project. the command block is:

```
commandtobq = "bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --field_delimiter=\"^|\" "
commandtobq += " " + gcptrendtable
commandtobq += " " + gsincomingfolder + filetrendoutputname
commandtobq += " \"" + filetrendschema + "\""
print(commandtobq)
os.system(commandtobq)
```

This produces the command:

```
bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --field_delimiter="^|"  AvgPDHrsAssoc.avgpdhrsassoc_trend_x 
gs://thd_tr_incoming/AvgPDHrsAssoc-Retail-Trend-GCP-Output-2019-10-23.csv 
"P:\Delivery Team\Execution Reports\Reports-Python\THD-TR-AvgPDHrsAssoc-Retail\SQLs\AvgPDHrsAssoc-Retail-LSR-Extract-v01-Trend-Schema.json"
```

When this command is copy/pasted into a command prompt window, it executes perfectly. When I use `os.system(commandtobq)` to execute it through python, it fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\bootstrapping\bq.py", line 10, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\os.py", line 411
    yield from walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I resolve this error? Note that I previously had Python 2.7 and 3.6 on the machine, but scrubbed both off for a fresh install of 3.8.

Any ideas would help! thank you!

Added this:
I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) as an IDE, in case that influences the problem or solution

Comment: It's not part of your problem, but the code you're running has serious security vulnerabilities. Using string concatenation to assemble OS commands is a very, **very** bad idea (as anyone who can provide arbitrary filenames can run arbitrary commands)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your program do

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.version)
```

It looks like you are a Python version before `yield from` was added, against a newer version of the library that uses `yield from`.

Count the number of `Python*.exe` files you have. You aren't using the one that lives in `C:\Python38-32`.

The `google-cloud-sdk` for Windows has the option to have its own bundled Python 2.7. Installing 3.8 might have caused this Python to attempt using the library that comes with 3.8.

Comment: I have `import sys` in the code. The `sys.version` comes out as `3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]`

Comment: I'm searching for other Python.exe's on my C-Drive

Comment: Your comment about the google-cloud-sdk sounds correct. the whole traceback is: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\bin\bootstrapping\bq.py", line 10, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\os.py", line 411
    yield from walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: How do I fix that?